# Windows Terminal no longer lists Ubuntu bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 10.0.21337 (windows insider program) and installed WSL and Windows Terminal which listed powershell, cmd.exe, Ubuntu bash and azure as profiles.
I made the Ubuntu bash the default and this worked fine for a while.

After a restart I was warned that the chosen default guid is not valid. Also, Ubuntu is no longer listed in the menu but the other three are. Here's the relevant snippet in settings.json:

```
        {
            "guid": "{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f518}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"
        },
```

In another computer (Win 10 Pro 10.0.19041) I still have the same settings and they work.

What does `"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"` mean exactly? Does it point to some other config? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: To make Windows Terminal add all your installed WSL distros again to the profiles menu just remove the file `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\state.json` (or preferably move it to another directory in case you want to keep a backup). This file contains all the previously generated dynamic profiles that has been added to Windows Terminal. By removing the file Windows Terminal will scan for all installed WSL distros and add them the next time you start Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

> What does `"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"` mean exactly? Does it point to some other config? How is it supposed to work?

A `source` tells Windows Terminal to  [dynamically create a profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles) from that particular "source".  `Windows.Terminal.Wsl` is an source *internal* to Windows Terminal that reads the WSL distributions you have installed and generates a profile for each one of them.

It checks this and adds the entries each time WSL is launched, and the guid which is assigned should always be the same based on a combination of the source and the distribution name.  You can see some of the technical details [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/specs/#754%20-%20Cascading%20Default%20Settings.md#dynamic-profiles).

It sounds like, for some reason, either the guid itself changed, or the variables on which the guid is constructed changed (or WT *thinks* it changed).

Deleting the profile entry entirely *should* allow it to regenerate the next time you launch Windows Terminal.  But ... it *should* already be regenerating it anyway since the guid is no longer matching its calculated value, so deleting the profile may not work.  It's still worth a try.

Another option is to make a back-up of your settings, delete the `settings.json` and let it regenerate the whole thing from scratch.  This is (currently, IMHO) a good thing to do every now and then anyway, as the "boilerplate" that is generated will often include some helpful new information/defaults.  Then copy over any customizations from your backup to the newly generated one.  Note that this advice *may* quickly be outdated as the new "Settings" UI should be available soon.

You've already found that you can set the `commandline` manually.  In this case, you should just delete the `source` setting.  You may also want to add a `"disabledProfileSources"` (example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles#prevent-a-profile-from-being-generated)) to stop it from attempting to regenerate it dynamically in that case.

Finally, per your self-answer, you are using `bash.exe`.  I personally recommend switching to `wsl.exe` as that command provides more options.  For instance, you may want to make it `wsl.exe ~` to start in your home directory.  While `bash.exe` is still valid, Microsoft has made it clear that it is a "historical command" which has been "replaced by wsl.exe" (quoting from various MS pages).  It's not-quite-deprecated, but they certainly recommend using `wsl.exe` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by adding the following line in the ubuntu snippet:

```
            "commandline": "bash.exe",
```

I still don't know how `"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"` is or should be interpreted and why it used to work earlier.